# How to load a basic module from a cron job

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, cron, gae-module

I am having trouble loading my GAE module.

My cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: call frontend instance to call module
  url: /callLoadAndProcess
  schedule: every day 01:00
  timezone: America/New_York
```

Then the relevant part of my app.yaml:

```
- url: /callLoadAndProcess
  script: callLoadAndProcess.application
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

Now my callLoadAndProcess.py:

```
import sys
import webapp2
import os
import urllib2
import logging
from google.appengine.api import modules

class callLoadAndProcess(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        modules.start_module("loadandprocess","1")

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/callLoadAndProcess', callLoadAndProcess)],debug=True)
```

For my module, I have a loadandprocess.yaml, which is:

```
application: [application name]
module: loadandprocess
version: 1
runtime: python27
instance_class: B4_1G
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: loadAndProcess.application
  login: admin
```

And finally, loadAndProcess.py is the script I want run as a backend module:

```
class loadAndProcess(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            #DO STUFF

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/loadAndProcess', loadAndProcess)],debug=True)
```

In my development server, when I try to run the cron job via the admin page, I get the following error:

```
line 138, in _CheckAsyncResult
raise mapped_error()
InvalidVersionError
```

I feel I set it up correctly... and the version numbers match.. did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: how do you start dev_server.py, can you post cmd line args?

Comment: Here's how I start my server:

dev_appserver.py [appname]/app.yaml [appname]/loadandprocess.yaml [appname]/dispatch.yaml

Answer (score 0):

To run the app locally, specify both `.yaml` files to `dev_appserver.py`:

```
dev_appserver.py -A your-app-id application.yaml worker.yaml
```

Comment: check the comments - that's already how the server is invoked (even better, the `dispatch.yaml` file is also included)